# Not able to configure my touchpad on the new lubuntu 16.04.

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, touchpad

Following is the output from my terminal

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GASIA USB KB V11                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GASIA USB KB V11                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Laptop extra buttons                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.245295] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.248251] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.250328] pnp 00:05: [dma 3]
[    0.250524] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0401 (active)
[    0.251966] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.252506] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
[    2.391026] isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
[    2.794567] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    2.808400] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```